# Running a Python script from a personal website?

Tags: python, user-interface, web

I have a personal website and I want to add a few programs I have written in Python on it. They are basic genome search scripts.

The programs take an amino acid sequence as input, scan a database, and return a list of matches as output. I would like to make this an interactive app that I can put on my website (hosted on godaddy).

Thanks.

Comment: You can try a web framework, I develop with pyramid here is the link http://www.pylonsproject.org

Answer (score 1):

You should use a web framework of some kind. In that you can make views that call the methods you have in your script.

Good frameworks in this case would probably be something minimal, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

Answer (score -1):

Look into CGI-Scripting. The idea is that instead of serving up a static HTML file, the server runs a script (in your case, python) that prints the html to the webpage. The script can take in form values, do manipulations with them (searching a database, for example), and put out HTML dependent on program logic. See here for some examples: http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts

You could also have the webpage be driven by another language more commonly used for this task like php and have the php code use your python scripts. That might make some things easier, but would add a layer of complication that you might not want, however.

Comment: CGI is a bad match with Python.

Comment: Reasoning? I've used it in the past for simple webpages and it was perfectly adequate. If the programs are already written in python, then it seems a natural choice. I'll talk about other options, though.

Comment: Well, it's really slow, as a starter. And it also requires much more knowledge of HTTP than necessary with a proper framework. And you get encoding issues you have to deal with. CGI is just stupid, doubly so with Python.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit old-school and prefer to reinvent the wheel when it comes to stuff like this. Frameworks are great, but seems a bit overkill for simple applications. Definitely subject to personal preference to some extent, though.